# How to allow certain HTML tags with htmlentites() in php

Tags: php, html

I want to allow tags such as `<B>` and `<I>` and other tags that users could modify their comments with.

Comment: http://ir1.php.net/strip_tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [strip_tags][1]

```
strip_tags ( $str, "<i><b>");
```

This will remove any other tags than `<i>` and `<b>`
[1]:https://www.php.net/strip_tags